# matching elements in a vector

Tags: c++

What i want to do is to match allow user to enter for example ID and match that ID with some vector and print it. Here is how my class looks like. (I am trying to do an inventory program).

```
class Item{
private:
  string month;
  string name;
  int ID;
  int actual_qunatity;

public:
  void print()const;
  void report();
  void getdata();
  void setname (string itemname){name=itemname;}
  void setID(int setID){ID=setID;}
};
class Inventory{
public:
  void print2()const;
  void report();
  void getdata();
  void sale();
private:
      vector<Item>items;
};
```

after adding elements to the vector i want to find some element in the vector and print it. here is

```
void Inventory::sale(){                                                                                                                                                               
  int ID;
  cout<<"Enter ID ";
  cin>>ID;
  vector<Item>::const_iterator it;
  it=find(items.begin(), items.end(), ID);
  ++it;
}
```

but i get an error: no matching function for call to 'find(std::vector::iterator, std::vector::iterator, int&)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is because you have a vector of `Item` objects and you are telling it to look for an integer. You need to either change your design or simply use a for loop and manually do the check on each object somewhat like this:

```
std::vector<Item>::const_iterator it;
for(it = items.begin(); it != items.end(); it++) {
    if (it->ID == ID) {
        // this is your element
    }
}
```

Comment: but this says that ID is private

Comment: I think in this context though a getter for the ID wouldn't hurt at all so that could be a solution. Otherwise, my answer is no good. Thanks for pointing it out !

Comment: if I declare getID{return ID;} in a item class then to find an element how would i use it? i tried something like this if (it->getID() == id)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and a lambda to perform the search.

```
int ID;
cout << "Enter ID ";
cin >> ID;
auto it = find_if(items.begin(), items.end(), [&]( Item const& item ) {
                   return item.getID() == ID; // need to be able to access ID 
                                            // publicly
                  } );

if( it != items.end() ) {
  // it points to item with matching ID
}
```

Comment: if I declare getID{return ID;} in a item class then to find an element how would i use it? i tried something like this if (it->getID() == id)

Comment: Declare it as `int getID() const {return ID;}` and you can use it as shown in the snippet above.

Comment: thanks, one more question why does it when i print the items if i don't put a cost on it then on the first item it prints 0 but on other one like 4.59163e-41

Comment: I can't say for sure without seeing some code. Sounds like you might be trying to access something that's gone out of scope or pointing to invalid memory.

Comment: how would you change an quantity after a matched ID has been found? for example i use getquantity()const{return actual_quantity) but then replace it with something else?

Comment: You need a function that can set the quantity, maybe `void setQuantity( int )`?

Comment: yes i have void setactual(int qunatity){actual_quantity=qunatity;} but how would you assign it in the for loop above? it->setactual(amount) doesn't work

Comment: That should work. You really should post a new question with code showing what isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

To look for a specific item inside a `vector<T>` you can't just let your code guess that you want to check for the `ID` field. First you need to write a custom comparison operator:

```
bool operator== ( const Item &n1, const Item &n2) {
  return n1.ID == n2.ID;
}
```

Then you should use a dummy item (with its constructor) to search for the specified item:

```
std::find(items.begin(), items.end(), Item(ID));
```

You can also iterate on the vector and look for the specified ID. Or even better, use a `map<int, Item>` or an `unordered_map` if you don't need random access to the vector.

Comment: Don't forget to declare `bool operator== ( const Item &n1, const Item &n2)` as friend function inside Item class;

Comment: Yes, for sure in this case since `ID` is private. But `friend` access wasn't directly related to OP question, that's why I avoided it.